# Reading binary file in C wrong output

Tags: c, binary, hex

I'm trying to read a binary file and print each byte inside as 2hex digits, but when 
I get to a space my program prints '0' when it should be '20' and it does this for every 20

my output `0 17 FF FF FF FF 0 0 17 FF FF FF FF FF 0 0 0 FF 0 0`

output from http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html

```
20 17 FF FF FF FF 20 20 17 FF FF FF FF FF 20 20 20 FF 20 20
```

does anyone know whats going on?
file = `ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿ`

```
//Read the test.bin file!!
#include<stdio.h>
   char initial[] = "test.bin";
struct rec{
   unsigned char mydata;
};
int readfile(char []){
   int counter;
   FILE *ptr_myfile;
   struct rec my_record;
   ptr_myfile=fopen(initial,"r");
   if (!ptr_myfile){
      printf("Unable to open file!");
      return 1;
   }
   for ( counter=1; counter <= 20; counter++){
      fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct rec),1,ptr_myfile);
      printf("%X\n",my_record.mydata);      
   }
   fclose(ptr_myfile);
   return 0;
}
int main(){
   readfile(initial);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check the return of `fread()`.   What would happen with your program if test.bin is an empty file?

Comment: If the file is binary, then you should [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) it in binary mode.

Comment: Are you sure that the file actually has 0x20 in those places, i.e., did you look at it with a hex editor or hexdump, or is your only reference the online converter?

Comment: Try fopen with "rb" instead of "r".

Comment: how did you get your binary file to that website?  it only takes things with text based encodings?

Comment: I copy/pasted the file to the website @arkku no I guess I can try with hexdump but space in ascii is 20 in hex so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the program

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly, but in copypasting the binary data to the website the `0x00` bytes end up turned into spaces, which have the value `0x20` in ASCII and compatible character sets.

Comment: ah ok I guess I should only use the site to convert from hex -> binary